# New Relic PlugIn SDK for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, newrelic-platform

According to the page [Choosing a development language for your plugin](https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/choosing-a-development-language-for-your-plugin) ,  there are PlugIn SDKs for  Java and Ruby.

For other platforms

> Less support is available from New Relic for language and development
>   tools for which we have not developed an SDK. Longer development time
>   is needed.

Does New Relic have plans to create similar PlugIn SDK for .Net?

Or anyone else created some New Relic PlugIn using .Net, that can be shared (may be consider open source project on GitHub) as a start point for other .Net plugIns?

Comment: What means down-vote without any comment? Does downvoter consider that .Net is so bad, that should not be used to write any plugins?

Comment: yeah, seems strange. you've got my upvote if it helps... :) btw you misspelled Ruby (although I doubt this is a reason to downvote)

Comment: "Does New Relic have plans to create similar PlugIn SDK for .Net?" - why not ask them directly?

Comment: @rup, at the bottom of the linked above page they suggested [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newrelic-platform) as a public forum.

Comment: They also give an email address. I still think it makes more sense to ask that part to them directly: the only people who can answer it are New Relic employees and whilst they might answer the tag here they'll definitely answer their support email.

Comment: @Rup, [nr-tony](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2356117/nr-tony) is in http://support.newrelic.com/, so I can consider [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256347/new-relic-plugin-sdk-for-net/17263902#17263902) as an official response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the Microsoft SQL server plugin: https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_microsoft_sqlserver_plugin

It's written in .Net.

Would love to see the work there turned into a generic SDK for .Net

Comment: The plugin includes [NewRelic.Platform.Binding.DotNET.dll](https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_microsoft_sqlserver_plugin/blob/develop/lib/NewRelic.Platform.Binding.DotNET.dll) . Is any documentation for the library available?

Comment: I would suggest you to include in your answers, that you are NewRelic employee. It will give more trust to your answers. Am I right, that SQL Server plugin was build by New Relic team?

Comment: The SQL Server Plugin was written by New Relic themselves, and does include a binding DLL that appears to match versions with the .NET Agent versioning. Wonder why they don't open source that, too?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there are no SDKs for other languages than Ruby or Java, you can still use the [New Relic API](https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/plugin-api-specification). It's a RESTful API and should be relatively easy to use.

For example, there are some plugins for New Relic written in Python (check out the [MeetMe plugin](https://github.com/MeetMe/newrelic-plugin-agent)). It doesn't use the SDK, but connects to New Relic via the API.

It could mean a little more work, but should be possible with .NET

Answer (score 0):

For those of you stumbling across this post a few years down the line (such as myself), it looks like the .Net SDK has now been open sourced:

https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_dotnet_sdk

I found the link to this repo buried in one of the documentation pages, despite most documentation states that only a Java and Ruby SDK are available.